# C# Invoke Chart

Tags: c#, асинхронность

Нужно сделать так чтобы было видно построение объекта в Chart, но при это не зависала программа.
Есть код без `Invoke` устраивает скорость, но зависает форма.

```
for (int i = 0; i < vectorDictionary.Count; i++)
        {
            List<PointF> l = vectorDictionary[i];
            for (int j = 0; j < l.Count; j++)
            {
                chart1.Series[i+1].Points.AddXY(l[j].X, l[j].Y);
                if(j%7==0)
                    chart1.Refresh();
            }
        }
```

С Invoke. Медленная скорость, так как много точек для построения

```
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < vectorDictionary.Count; i++)
                   {
                     List<PointF> l = vectorDictionary[i];
                     for (int j = 0; j < l.Count; j++)
                        {
                           chart1.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
                             {
                                   chart1.Series[i+1].Points.AddXY(l[j].X, l[j].Y);

                              }));


                         }
                    }
             });
```

Как добиться виденного построения без зависания формы?

Comment: делайте инвок на группу точек. скажем по 100 точек. Создавайте временный массив из точек, напишите функцию, которая его принимает и добавляет точки на график, а саму функцию уже вызывайте в Invoke

Comment: @АлексейОбухов пока так и сделал, может есть какой-то более правильный вариант

Comment: Можно попробовать сделать chart1.SuspendLayout() перед добавлением точек, а потом chart1.ResumeLayout(). Если конечно график является наследником Control.